# Apache Camel SWF does not schedule second Activity in the workflow

Tags: apache-camel, amazon-swf, apache-camel-aws

I have created a sample apache camel swf application based on Spring Boot. It works as expected for the first activity but even though it seems to schedule the second activity, the activity does not get invoked.

Reference to sample application - https://github.com/kpkurian/camel-aws-swf-shopping-cart-wf

The log shows below line

> 2018-01-18 00:23:32.705 DEBUG 9456 --- [erMasterQueue 1] o.apache.camel.processor.SendProcessor   : >>>> aws-swf://activity?activityList=&amazonSWClient=%23swfClient&domainName=name&eventName=<2nd activity name>&version=5.0

The history shows 2nd activity is not scheduled. I can see the WorkflowExecutionCompleted event in the end.

[2nd activity not scheduled screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BL4iA.png)

Comment: "activity does not get invoked" is not enough information. Look at the workflow history to see what's happening. Is activity scheduled and not started by a worker? Or it is not scheduled at all?

Comment: Hi @MaximFateev.. I have updated the question based on your feedback. Pl. let me know in case any other information is required. Thanks.

Comment: domain looks empty. Is it expected?

Comment: domain had a name within angular braces but the formatter seems to blank it out.. I have removed the angular braces

Comment: Sorry, I don't understand how apache camel works with SWF. Have you considered using AWS Flow Framework?

Comment: thanks @MaximFateev.. will take a look at AWS Flow Framework